# Refresh Parent Form after Quick Create in Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

In Dynamics CRM 2016 we have a Quick Create Form which works well. But once the Quick Create is done, and the record is saved (and the new record appears in the sub-grid in the parent form), the roll-up field under the sub-grid doesn't get re-refreshed on the screen until the user presses F5.

(we have some C# code to update the roll-up).

Does anyone know how to force the refresh of the main form after the Quick Create has successfully run?

[image]

Comment: Roll-up fields don't get calculated automatically

Comment: yes, we've got a C# plugin that does it. but the new value still doesn't display until after the F5

Comment: ok, so the roll-up field is recalculated, just the UI is not updated

Comment: sorry yes. i just edited the issue to clarify. i should've written "refreshed" not "re-calculated". sorry, am new to CRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add timeout on refresh event, and after 1-2 sec refresh once more.

```
function OnFormLoad() //add this function onload form
    {
      var subGrid = window.parent.document.getElementById("id of your subgrid")
      if (subGrid !== null) {
        if (subGrid.control)
          subGrid.control.add_onRefresh(fnOnRefresh)
        else
          setTimeout(OnFormLoad, 500);
      } else {
        setTimeout(OnFormLoad, 500);
      }
    }

function fnOnRefresh() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("id of your subgrid").refresh();
      }, 2000) //after 2 sec refresh subgrid
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Timur U ... i've got that working, and it is refreshing the sub-grid. but the rollup field below it on the main form still isn't updating. I've attached an image now too, so you can see the rollup field I'm trying to refresh - you can see the numbers there don't add up, until the user presses F5 or the refresh on the bottom right.

Answer (score 0):

I would try stopping the OOB save event using the below snippet: [Read more](https://neilparkhurst.com/2015/11/11/javascript-prevent-save/)

```
function onSave(context) {

  var saveEvent = context.getEventArgs();
  saveEvent.preventDefault();

//save explicitly here 

//reload the window here

}
```

And then save the entity in code using:

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
```

And then refresh/reload the browser window. I haven’t tried this but very rough theory :)

Answer (score 0):

We got it working ... used what Timur suggested but just changed the last function to:

```html
function fnOnRefresh() {
      setTimeout(function() {
  window.parent.location.reload(true);
      }, 500)
    }
```

Thank you